# BannerTime in MacOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey

In the past, I could manipulate the time a notification banner appears:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime SECONDS
```

With Monterey this is not longer working, what alternative way is there now?